# The shortest code to tell if a number is even or odd

Tags: code-golf, c, c++

One of my colleagues proposed us a challenge: to write the shortest C/C++ program to determine if a number is even or odd.

These are the requirements:

- Get a number from keyboard, at run-time (not from command line)
- Output the string `pari` if the number is even
- Output the string `dispari` if the number is odd
- We can assume that the input is legal
- We can assume that the machine has a i386 architecture
- Code preprocessing is not allowed (e.g.: use `#define`s)
- [edit after comments] The code can be considered valid if it compiles with `gcc 4.x`

This is the best attempt we had so far (file test.c, 50B):

```
main(i){scanf("%d",&i);puts("dispari"+3*(~i&1));}
```

Do you think we can go further?

<sub>(*): "dispari" is the italian for odd and "pari" is the italian for even</sub>

Comment: Is this for C or C++? In C++, that code is invalid. I believe in C as well.\

Comment: @LuchianGrigore, you can use both C and C++. The choice depends on the language that lets you write the shortest code. The code above compiles correctly with gcc, maybe I should add that as a requirement.

Comment: Sorry, but your best example doesn't compile with gcc 4.6.3 (Edit: it does)

Comment: @niomaster, I have the same version and it works, but not if the file extension is different than `.c`. Anyway, if you think that doesn't work, you could try providing your shortest working solution :).

Comment: Slight variation (untested): use return value of `scanf` to shorten into `main(i){puts("dispari"+3*(scanf("%d",&i)&~i));}`.

Comment: @Howard that works with gcc 4.6.3!

Comment: @Jack, my solution is C, yours could be C++, hence the tag. We are not interested in warnings here, this is just a stupid competition between too nerdish colleagues!

Comment: @VincenzoPii: Ok. Removed comment. I'm sorry, I'm in the sense of `stackoverflow.com`.

Comment: You can't legally and portably perform output without either `#include <stdio.h>` (which is a preprocessor directive) *or* your own declaration of the routines you're using. As of C90, calling an undeclared function has defined behavior only in narrow circumstances; as of C99, it's a constraint violation (C's version of "illegal").

Comment: Why no other languages allowed?! I like Perl so much ._. `print<><0?dis:$,,pari`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 39 bytes

Given you didn't specified the range of the number input, then here's a solution that handles 0..9 only:

```
main(){puts("dispari"-~getchar()%2*3);}
```

Answer (score 8):

### 47 bytes (2 less)

```
main(i){scanf("%d",&i);puts("dispari"-~i%2*3);}
```

For a positive `i`, `~i` is negative, so `~i%2` is 0 or -1.

Answer (score 3):

## 48 bytes

```
main(i){scanf("%d",&i);puts("dispari"+3-i%2*3);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### 34 bytes

Build with

```
gcc -nostartfiles -Wl,-ea odd.c
```

Works in GCC 6.3.0.

```
a(){puts("dispari"-~getch()%2*3);}
```